# Values not being pushed to an array inside of a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, stack, push

I am having an issue with a JavaScript Method a game that I am making that will be similar to the popular game 2048, but with a board of any size.

this.board is a property of the game object and is a n by n array that has either 0 or a number in it. this.board[row][column]

For example:

Where SIZE_OF_BOARD = 5; this.board[i] could be [0,0,2,4,0] at the end of the method the desired appearance of this.board[i] would be [0,0,0,2,4], but currently it is [0,0,0], the 2 and 4 are not being pushed to stack inside the column.

My problem is inside the column loop nothing is being pushed to the stack.

```
game.prototype.right = function () {
    for(var i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BOARD; i++){ // row loop
      var zeroCount = 0;
      var temp = 0;
      var stack = [];

      console.log(this.board[i]);
      for(var j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_BOARD; j++){ // column loop
        if(this.board[i][j] == 0){
          zeroCount++;
        } else if (temp == this.board[i][j] && temp != 0){
          stack.push(temp*2);
          zeroCount++;
          temp = 0;
        } else if (temp!=0){
          temp = this.board[i][j];
          stack.push(temp);
        }
      } 
      console.log(stack);
      while(zeroCount > 0){ // add the 0's to the left of the stack.
        stack.unshift(0);
        zeroCount--;
      }
      this.board[i] = stack;
      console.log(stack);
    }
    // this.next();
  }
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Why are you incrementing `zeroCount` in the case where `board[i][j] != 0`?

Comment: The 3 cases in you `if/elseif/elseif` make no sense. Either the element is zero or it's not zero, there's no third option.

Comment: Ah I see was was wrong, thank you so much :), I changed the last else if statement to just else, and removed the zeroCount++; in the first if statement. again, thanks heaps mate.

Comment: @Barmar I re added the zeroCount++; but I have to pop a value off the stack before pushing temp*2 to it. again thank you.

Comment: Changing the last `else if` to `else` won't help. The first two cases cover both possibilities, you'll never get into the `else`.

Comment: I don't understand what this code is trying to do, so I can't really advise on the right way to write it.

Comment: I've never heard of the game 2048, maybe if I knew what that was I might understand what this does.

Comment: As of now you won't ever get into the elseif's because temp is set to 0 for each row iteration and both the elseif's require temp to be non-zero. your if does not change temp, so the loop will never access either of the elseif's